# Django middleware vs mixin

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-oauth

I am using oauth2_provider library. However they have not given an end point to check if a access token is valid. [Token Introspection rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) says this is one non-normative way of doing so

```
 POST /introspect HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

 token=mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM&token_type_hint=access_token
```

However oauth2_provider lib doesn't provide any way to check if a client has correct credentials or not. To check that should I add a middleware to my request and decorate the view like is done by [`CSRFExepmtMixin`](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_forms.py#L11) or should I write a mixin like [`ProtectedResourceMixin`](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/mixins.py#L197)  ?

Comment: …or a class decorator might work as well, dynamically wrapping the views's `dispatch` method. Your pick. The middleware approach is good if you need to blanket you whole site with credentials check. Mixin/decorator is good if you only need to do it on a few specific views.

Comment: Note that a mixin or *class* decorator will only work with class-based views...